# ASPNET Core OIDC Correlation Failed

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have looked at a bunch of similar issues on StackOverflow similar to this but none of the solutions have worked for me.

This issue is driving me nuts!

The main difference I have from many of the similar ones here is that I have only ONE server behind the load balancer, so the issue is not that my requests are going to different servers. I have implemented Data Protection middleware, changed my callback path, tried to capture error events, added a cache for state data, etc. Nothing has solved this. I don't know what I am missing.

If anyone can provide me some insight on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.ClientId = Configuration["IdServerClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["IdServerClientSecret"];
                options.Authority = Configuration["IdServerBaseUri"];
                options.CallbackPath = "/sign-in-oidc2";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                };
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                {
                    //OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToProvider,
                    OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure,
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                };
            });

        services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache("foo");

        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration["KeyPersistenceLocation"]));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer here if anyone else encounters this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1#when-it-isnt-possible-to-add-forwarded-headers-and-all-requests-are-secure

In the Configure method on Startup, need to add this for handling http/https conflicts.

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next();
});
```