# OIDC login redirect back gives 500 error (signin-oidc)

Tags: openid-connect, .net-core-2.2

I am using .NET Core 2.2 for my webapi application !
It is running without problem on my local computer, On staging environment I am getting "Correlation failed (unknown location)" error message just after succesfull login. (login happens on another domain and redirects back to my application)

Before adding following code in my startup.cs file, I was not even getting redirect to my application after succesfull login, now I am getting redirect to my application with 500 error message.

```
        var forwardingOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        };
        forwardingOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear(); //its loopback by default
        forwardingOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardingOptions);
```

[image]

```
           .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = tokenServiceConfig.Authority;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = tokenServiceConfig.RequireHttpsMetadata;

                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/Inloggen/LoggedOut";

                options.Scope.Add("somescope1");
                options.Scope.Add("somescope2");
                options.Scope.Add("somescope3");

                options.ClientId = tokenServiceConfig.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = tokenServiceConfig.ClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.ResponseMode = "form_post";

                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;
            });
```

Comment: did the answer work? I am having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

[ASPNET Core OIDC Correlation Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449650/aspnet-core-oidc-correlation-failed)

In the Configure method on Startup, need to add this for handling http/https conflicts.

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next();
});
```